# Integrating BIM and ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-platform, bim, revit, ifc

I have a 3D building done using Revit , i have exported the file using FME extension into IFC file in order to make the integration with ArcGIS ! i didn't find the way to make this happen , the only way i have discovered is to export the IFC file to KML. so any one got an idea the process of the integration BIM & ArcGIS.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options that are available.  You can bring Revit data into Arc but I believe you need to export the revit model into an IFC file, you would then use data interoperability to import that into the geo-database.

https://geonet.esri.com/thread/141610 - a good source that I think explains what you want to do.

I know of one firm that does this using Safe FME desktop, which may be easier but of course it would require a license.  Below are some web pages that will give you a good idea of where to start. This is a very broad question so its hard to give you any specifics other than pointing you to this data.

http://www.safe.com/webinar/bim-and-gis-integration/  -  a very good primer on BIM and GIS, but it assumes you are also using Safe FME Desktop.

http://www.aturnofthenut.com/2014/07/22/exporting-from-revit-2014-bim-to-arcgis/  -  a very good comprehensive article

http://communityhub.esriuk.com/geoxchange/2012/5/23/what-is-bim-and-where-does-gis-fit-in.html

Comment: Thank you so much ! Yes i have succeeded to make the integration using FME but only with google earth "KML" files . didn't realize that i could do it also for the arcgis files . By the way i hav already my Revit files ready to implement and exported as IFC so i think am gonna try these things.

appreciate your answer

Thanks